# Empty MYSQL table columns

Tags: mysql

We have a legacy system where we believe some columns have never been used. This is because a setup was repeated for new clients.

Is there any simple way in mysql to check for empty columns in a table other than doing a check one column at a time?

Comment: *Is there any simple way in mysql to check for empty columns in a table other than doing a check one column at a time?* Of course. You can start parallel checking for a lot of columns.

Comment: Drop the columns you are not sure are used, and see if anyone complains? :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  SUM(col1 IS NOT NULL),   -- if "empty" means NULL
        SUM(col2 != ''),         -- if "empty" means empty-string
        ...
     FROM tbl;
```

A non-zero result means that the column is 'not empty'.